# ${coord:nominalTime()} does not resolve nominal_time in Oozie coordinator job

Tags: oozie-coordinator

```
<coordinator-app name="tmpfile-processor" frequency="${coord:hours(1)}"
    start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="America/Chicago" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4" xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.2">
    <action>
            <workflow>
                    <app-path>${workflowAppUri}</app-path>
                    <configuration>
                            <property>
                                    <name>jobTracker</name>
                                    <value>${jobTracker}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                    <name>nameNode</name>
                                    <value>${nameNode}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                    <name>queueName</name>
                                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                            </property>
                    </configuration>
            </workflow>
            <sla:info>
                    <sla:nominal-time>${coord:nominalTime()}</sla:nominal-time>
                    <sla:should-start>${1 * MINUTES}</sla:should-start>
                    <sla:should-end>${1 * MINUTES}</sla:should-end>
                    <sla:max-duration>${1 * MINUTES}</sla:max-duration>
                    <sla:alert-events>start_miss,end_miss,duration_miss</sla:alert-events>
                    <sla:alert-contact>user@xxx.com</sla:alert-contact>
            </sla:info>
    </action>
```

Error: variable [nominal_time] cannot be resolved

As I understood, the function coord:nominalTime() should return the nominal_time based on the start time and frequency. Is there anything wrong with the xmlns label version or something else?

Comment: Comment #1: the error message displayed is quite bizarre because there is no `nominal_time` in the **Coordinator shown**. On the other hand, that message would make sense if you had run a copy-paste of the **Workflow code samples** -- which require *implicitly* that the Coordinator define a Workflow property `nominal_time` based on `coord:nominalTime()`

Comment: Comment #2: the documentation for SLA asserts that  `uri:oozie:sla:0.2` requires *"workflow/coordinator schema to **0.5**"* -- while your sample states **0.4** (http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_SLAMonitoring.html#Configuring_SLA_in_Applications)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have seen the doc you mentioned. You may have noticed that in section "SLA Definition in Coordinator Action", it uses xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4" with xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.2".

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Actually coordinator 0.5 does not exist at all. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.oozie/oozie-client/4.0.0-cdh5.0.2/oozie-coordinator-0.4.xsd?av=f

Comment: So you know how reliable the Oozie documentation is...   ;-) some features are not documented, some are documented but don't work. Unless you can bribe an Oozie committer, forget about this SLA feature.

Comment: I think I have seen this if initial-instance is greater than start-time. Check that.